# How to add multiple fields simultaneously into sql databse using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am writing a function which takes an object and an user id to insert data into a table called userdetails, the fields should be updated if they are not null, is there any short way to write the sql query. I am using mysql for database connection.

```
class UserDetails {
  constructor(options) {
    this.setFields(options);
  }

  setFields(options) {
    this.id = options.id || null;
    this.userId = options.userId || null;
    this.firstName = options.firstName || null;
    this.lastName = options.lastName || null;
    this.location = options.location || null;
    this.interests = options.interests || null;
    this.avatar = options.avatar || null;
  }

  /**
   * Update the details of the user
   * @param {Number} userId ID of the user
   * @param {Object} fields Contains the fields of the data to be updated
   */
  async updateDetails(userId, fields) {
    this.userId = userId;
    const fieldNames = ['id','firstName','lastName','location','interests','avatar'];

    const {id,firstName,lastName,location,interests,avatar} = fields;

    // do something

  }
}
```